# Bindy skipping empty csv files

Tags: java, apache-camel, bindy

I built a camel route that unmarshals a csv file using camel bindy and writes the contents to a database. This works perfectly apart from when the file is empty, which by the looks of it will happen a lot. The file does contain csv headers, but no relevant data e.g.:

```
CODE;CATEGORY;PRICE;
```

In this case the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No records have been defined in the CSV
```

I tried adding `allowEmptyStream = true` to the bindy object that I use for unmarshalling. This however does not seem to do much, as the same error appears.

Any ideas on how to skip processing these empty files is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, the option [`allowEmptyStream`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html#_dataformat_option_allowEmptyStream) must be set to `true` at Bindy DataFormat level, as next:

```
BindyCsvDataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(SomeModel.class);
bindy.setAllowEmptyStream(true);

from("file:some/path")
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    // The rest of the route
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: It will not work giving error "The method setAllowEmptyStream(Boolean) is undefined for the type BindyCsvDataFormat